# The role of Intermediate Users in the Retweeting Chain

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been developing a nodes/edges network between Twitter users using `tweepy` (although I'm flexible to use other libraries). Is it possible to establish a retweeting pattern among users?

For example, let's say `A` is followed by `B` who is followed by `C` who does NOT follow `A`. `B` retweets `A`'s tweet about a football match. `C` retweets the retweet from `B` (not directly from `A`).

```
A -> B -> C
```

Unfortunately the `tweepy` method I've been using links `C`'s retweet straight to `A`, ignoring `B`'s role as intermediary (which is important to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy does not allow for this kind of retweet-chain analysis because the Twitter API `Tweet` object does not include information on from whom the tweet was retweeted. From the description of the `retweeted_status` field:

> This attribute contains a representation of the original Tweet that was retweeted. Note that retweets of retweets do not show representations of the intermediary retweet, but only the original tweet. - [Twitter API (Tweet Object)](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets)

So unfortunately, this is not possible with the present Twitter API.

Comment: "Tweepy does not allow for this kind of retweet-chain analysis " do other libraries allow that? Luigi ci possiamo sentire via mail?magari ci possiamo scambiare qualche dritta!